# Cutting down large matrix iteration time

Tags: matlab

I have some massive matrix computation to do in MATLAB.  It's nothing complicated (see below).  I'm having issues with making computation in MATLAB efficient.  What I have below works but the time it takes simply isn't feasible because of the computation time.

```
for i = 1 : 100
   for j = 1 : 20000
      element = matrix{i}(j,1);
      if element <= bigNum && element >= smallNum
         count = count + 1; 
      end    
   end    
end
```

Is there a way of making this faster?  MATLAB is meant to be good at these problems so I would imagine so?

Thank you :).

Comment: Is `matrix` a matrix or a cell array? If all your rows have the same number of columns, there is no point in treating it like a cell array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
count = 0
for i = 1:100
    count = count + sum(matrix{i}(:,1) <= bigNum & matrix{i}(:,1) >= smallNum);
end
```

Comment: Thank you Jouni... Way faster.  Is it faster because sum is very efficient i.e. I guess the compiler is good at applying a single operator to a vector of numbers?

Comment: @vivid-colours: Yes, that's one of the basic design features of Matlab. Also, it's the interpreter, not the compiler ;)

Comment: Woops, interpreter thank you :p.  My respect for MATLAB is increasing after seeing these speedups :).

Comment: Actually, modern versions of Matlab include a JIT compiler. Also, I'm not Jonas. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If your `matrix` is a matrix, then this will do:

```
count = sum(matrix(:) >= smallNum & matrix(:) <= bigNum);
```

If your matrix is really huge, use [`anyExceed`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27857). You can profile (check the running time) of both functions on `matrix` and decide.

Comment: anyExceed checks if there are any elements outside the range and returns after it finds the first one, right? It's not good for counting the number of elements outside the range.